# Create the underlined font in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, underline, nsfont

ALL,

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) NSFont has only method to retrieve the underline font parameters.

Is there a way to set the font to be underlined?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to set the font to be underlined?

No, but that's just because you're barking up the wrong tree.

A "font" can't be underlined, (at least, I don't think), but a string can be.

Look at NSAttributedString...  You create a dictionary of "attributes", which you attach to the NSString you want to draw... "Obliqueness", (means Italic or not), "Centered"... all that stuff.  So it's like this:

```
[textAttrDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
[textStr drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:textAttrDict];
```

Search for the NSUnderlineStyleSingle in the headers to find the exact enum that you want...

Comment: Well the font can't be Bold, it is a string renderer that paints the sring bold. However, using NSFontManager, I can create a Bold type font. I was thinking that something like this is available under font.... Guess I was wrong ;-)